# solr group functions for processing the secondly present group value

Tags: function, solr, grouping

I'm using solr 4.3.0 and I'm using group functions for getting the desired item details. My requirement is to get the second minimum value from each group. I tried using `group.truncate` function where I'm able to apply it only for the first value from each group. Can anyone help me out to solve this?

Comment: This seems to me a X&Y problem [1] .
Can you please specify your original problem and we can find a Solr solution for it  ( that maybe does not involve grouping at all) :)

[1] http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: im using Grouop functions for my requirement where i have product and item details in each group.For a group there will be one product and n items.Im grouping id by common group_id.My requirement is to do faceting for the price range in a query where i need to consider only the item's (price_USD)minimum price and also to show the product details.If i use grouoping means facet price_range considering all items and product price_usd but i need to consider only the min priced item value from each group.

Comment: Using nested Object modelling[1] and Json faceting[2] seems a better fit for me .
The parent can be the product and the item details the children.
At this point you can search on parents and then retrieve the children or any other similar task.

Tou can use json faceting to get the stat you are expecting.

[1] http://yonik.com/solr-nested-objects/
[2] http://yonik.com/solr-json-request-api/

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use `group.sort` or `sort` to order the documents inside each group (`fieldname asc`), and then return at least two documents in each group (`group.limit=2`). The second lowest value will be the second document in each group.

Comment: i need to use this second value (price) for calculating price range in facet where i need to include only second min.value for faceting